# Sendgrid - Activity says email delivered but email not received

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I tried to send an email through sendgrid. I have a custom domain myself@contoso.com. If i try to send an email to user1@gmail.com with the from address as myself@contoso.com,then,the email is delivered to gmail with "via". When i try sending email to myself@contoso.com with the from address being myself@contoso.com the activity says the email is delivered however, in outlook client i have not received the email. What is it that I can try or do?

I have tried whitelisting contoso.com but it did not work

Comment: I was sending mail to a shared mailbox and it wasn't getting delivered until I completed the 'Verify Domain` step.

Comment: I too facing the same problem with some emails on a particular domain, If anybody provides your suggestions would be very helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: I have this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77766652/emails-with-links-to-my-website-sent-via-sendgrid-to-professional-email-addresse

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer, as it doesn't help work out why the emails that are "Delivered" have not been received, but this is [SendGrid's note on why Email messages with the “Delivered” status are not received](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041356754-Email-messages-with-the-Delivered-status-are-not-received):

> Twilio SendGrid posts the Delivered event after the destination server accepts the message with a 250 OK response. Once an email is accepted by the destination server, we are unable to see what happens to the message. The receiving server could send it to the inbox, queue it for later delivery, put it into the spam folder, etc.
> Often times, a recipient domain will initially accept a message for delivery, and then apply additional filtering afterwards. In this situation, we would have posted the Delivered event, but not have any insight into the additional filtering. Any additional Twilio SendGrid events for your email message would be triggered by recipient engagement (i.e. open/click events, unsubscribes, etc.).

Also note that at the time of writing, that answer had 26 downvotes (and zero upvotes) on the SendGrid website, probably indicating that many other users have experienced this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. Domain authentication was setup, and emails were being delivered fine to gmail. However, O365 seemed to be having a problem delivering the emails to the inbox, even though SendGrid was showing as delivered.

I would suggest everyone head to https://mxtoolbox.com and look up your domain. See if you have a DMARC policy set. I did not have one set, as soon as I set one I starting receiving emails to O365.

You can use this site https://dmarcian.com/dmarc-record-wizard/ to generate a DMARC policy. Then all you have to do is add a txt record to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had several issue solving this problem. The most important part is to set "Sender Authentication" from sendgrid to your domain dns. There is a instruction [here](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth). I'm using godaddy, so the link to set dns is https://dcc.godaddy.com/manage//dns .

Comment: Without authentication, sendgrid doesn't allow to send emails. The op mentions that emails are being delivered to sendgrid server but not outlook server, he/she must have authentication set up already.