# Emails with links to my website sent via Sendgrid to professional email addresses are not being delivered

Tags: email, sendgrid, strapi

I use SendGrid to send emails, which contain a link to my website. However, they are not being delivered to professional email addresses (but according to the activity in the SendGrid tool, it says that it is delivered). They work well with Gmail addresses (user with gmail always gets email). Additionally, they work with professional addresses if I remove the link from the emails.

and in the beginning worked well with all the emails.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After removing the `clicktracking="off"` property from the links in the email, users started receiving emails.